# MySQL How do I create a UNION and check results from both selects?

Tags: mysql, union

Example of what I would like to do

```
(SELECT name result FROM stuff2,finding) h 
UNION 
(SELECT name result FROM stuff2 where h.name != stuff2.name)
```

How do I check values between union?

NOTICE I'm calling a union on the same table.

Comment: What do you mean by "check values between union"? Are you asking how to determine which records are in both results?

Comment: The problem is I'm actually calling a union on the same table but I'm displaying different values for each select

Comment: Maybe you should just show the schema and explain what you want or provide sample result.

Comment: Why are you joining the table with itself? What are you trying to do that isn't possible without a join

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it: The explanation is not clear at all. Perhaps you should add the tables with some sample data and what you want as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the two subqueries that are unioned take data from different tables:

```
( SELECT * FROM stuffOne ) s 
UNION 
( SELECT * 
  FROM stuffTwo s2
  WHERE s2.name NOT IN
        ( SELECT name FROM stuffOne )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You want a JOIN instead:

```
SELECT s1.*, s2.*
FROM stuff2 AS s1
JOIN stuff2 AS s2
  ON s1.name != s2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use left join, like this:

```
select 
     stuff2.name,
     ISNULL(finding.result, stuff2.result) as result
from stuff2
left join finding
on stuff2.ID = finding.ID
```